# Ajax Update Panel Causes Full Page Load

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, updatepanel

I am using VB.Net and the problem is that my update panel  causes full page load no matter how I try. When I download sample codes from website and run, it works!!! Even if I copy the whole codes from those sample into my newly created webform and run, it still refreshes the whole page!! What could be the problem? 
PS. I've already tried  in my web.config and it didn't make different !! :(

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
   <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>How to use UpdatePanel</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />

        <asp:Label ID="lblTime1" runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="butTime1" runat="server" Text="Refresh Panel" /><br /><br />

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="butTime1" EventName="Click" />
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="butTime2" />
            </Triggers>

            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTime2" runat="server" /><br />
                <asp:Button ID="butTime2" runat="server" Text="Refresh Page" /><br />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <br />

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>

            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTime3" runat="server" /><br />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem>Change</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>My</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Value</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebForm1.aspx.vb**

```
 Public Partial Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        lblTime1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("T")
        lblTime2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("T")
        lblTime3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("T")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: PLease can you commit your code

Comment: Check ScriptManager's control `EnablePartialRendering` property value

Comment: I did add `EnablePartialRendering` but it still refreshes the whole page :( Is it my ajax problem? Why does it work fine if I run downloaded sample code but not when I copy and paste the exact code and run?

Comment: Please post the scripts your are loading... are you missing any jQuery references?

Comment: If you are coming from a search engine: Make sure you don't have a `Response.Redirect(...)` or the sort from the codebehind. I just lost half an hour for this reason.